# React js and redux form update content

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, redux

I have a redux form included as component within parent component render function.

The redux form fills form data from its `this.props`

Now I have a drop down in the parent component which I want to change the redux form content once dropdown changes its value.

My question is how to change the redux form content (which is `this.props`) from the parent component once dropdown clicked ?

Answer (score 1):

You should dispatch an action.

Have the parent component also listen to props. for the dropdown `onClick` function, you dispatch an action to update the redux store, and everything on the page will update that refers to those props.